# Cannot use Where and orderBy together in flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

```
Firestore.instance
.collection(this.collection)
.where('total', isEqualTo: 15)
.orderBy(this.orderByKey, descending: true)
.limit(limit)
.getDocuments();
```

If `where` and `orderBy` combined together it shows the following error

> NosuchMethodError: the getter 'length' was called on null.

If `where` or `orderBy` removed then code it works fine.

Comment: No solution? I'm having the exact same problem right now.. @Thamaraiselvam

Comment: Actually there is no solution, my db structure was flexible so I queried it another way.

Comment: Okay then, thanks for the reply. It's pretty weird how this thing is not working where it supposed to work..